# Print First Page Only from Context Menu

Tags: windows, microsoft-excel, pdf, printer, context-menu

I batch print Excel and PDF files regularly using the Print option in the Windows context menu (by right clicking on the files). The problem is that some files have several pages; is it possible to print first page only using the Context Menu (e.g. somehow add that option in the list)?

If not, are there other workarounds? My goal is not to open every file one at a time and manually select "Print First page only" or "Fit Sheet to One page."

OS: Windows 7.
Thanks.

Comment: What version of windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way is to add this procedure to your personal workbook (PERSONAL.XLSB) and a assign a keyboard shortcut to it:

```
Sub PrintFirstPage()
    ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut From:=1, To:=1
End Sub
```

Comment: OP cannot do this with PDF's

Comment: Yes this only works for Excel printing.

Comment: Am I correct that with this method I will need to open the excel files one at a time to use the shortcut key?

Comment: I used the procedure above with a keyboard shortcut and it works sufficiently. I still open files one at a time, but this is a solution nevertheless.